# Why are submersions open maps?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

I am trying to understand submersions and I ran into this explanation:

> A submersion is an open map. This is because locally there exists
> co-ordinates in which the submersion can be written as the projection
> onto the first few co-ordinates, which is an open map.

Why is this open? All I know about submersion is that by the local submersion theorem, around any point $p$ you can locally turn your submersion into the canonical projection onto the lesser dimensional space. i.e. you get $(x^1, ..., x^m) \rightarrow(x^1, ... , x^n)$ with $n < m$.

I don't see why this is open. For example take a closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and project it down onto its shadow in $\mathbb{R}^2$, well that is certainly a canonical projection since all we did is take out the last coordinate as required, but the image is the closed disk, so we are just mapping a closed set onto a closed set.

What am I misunderstanding? Is the theorem actually stating that the coordinates in the submersion span the whole of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to check whether a map is open, why are you starting with a closed set? Of course you won't get anywhere. Assume that $m>n$ and consider the projection $\pi\colon \Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R^n$. Let $\Omega\subseteq\Bbb R^m$ be open and let's show that $\pi[\Omega]\subseteq \Bbb R^n$ is open. Write $\Bbb R^m = \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^{m-n}$, so that $\pi$ reads $\pi(x,y) = x$. Let $x\in \pi[\Omega]$. Then there is $y\in \Bbb R^{m-n}$ such that $(x,y)\in \Omega$. Now since $\Omega$ is open there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B((x,y), \epsilon) \subseteq \Omega$. Then we claim that $B(x,\epsilon) \subseteq \pi[\Omega]$. Let $x' \in B(x,\epsilon)$, so that $\|x-x'\|<\epsilon$. Then $\|(x,y) - (x',y)\| = \|x-x'\| < \epsilon$, which says that $(x',y) \in B((x,y),\epsilon)$, so that $(x',y) \in \Omega$. This means that $x'\in \pi[\Omega]$, as desired.

(Here, we use the norm on $\Bbb R^m = \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^{m-n}$ given by $\|(x,y)\| = \|x\| + \|y\|$. Recall that all norms in finite dimensional vector spaces are equivalent.)

Comment: See this is the part I don't understand. "why are you starting with a closed set", because I don't see what about $\pi$ is makiing it act only on an open set. It is perfectly well defined to orthogonally project closed sets down onto lower euclidean spaces.

So, is it just that $\pi$ implicitly assumes that the domain is the whole of $R^m$? I just don't see what makes $\pi$ intriniscally open when the operation can be applied to open sets without any ambiguity.

Comment: The definition of "open map" is "taking open sets to open sets".

Comment: It's not acting only on open sets, it's that if you want to show a map is open, you start with an open set and you show the image of that open set is open. That's the definition of "open map". It doesn't matter where closed sets are sent under the map if all you're trying to prove is that the map is open.